# How to make a webpage accessible only once at one time?(JS+HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage (home.html) and I want it be accessible only once at a time.

That is, a person can enter that page the first time he/she opened. But while this page is viewing in a tab, another page will be opened if the person try to open home.html in a new tab.

How can I do that? Which JS function I need to add in my webpage?

Comment: It think this can be done using by cookies. if cookie is presented, then home.html redirects, or something similar.

Comment: You can `set a cookie` with `jquery.cookie.js` plugin. then detect if `cookie` set, do other thing.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` variables for this

Comment: Either localStorage or cookies, but both are easily editable by the client, hence you may have a little chance for someone to actually avoid your controls, despite it shouldn't be the biggest problem in this planet. (Also, different browsers -> different cookies -> multiple pages)

Comment: Is it possible to use <body onload="function()">???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local storage with trigger on body load/unload events:

```js
function session1() {

var result = localStorage.getItem("session");

if (result != "running") {
localStorage.setItem("session", "running");
} else if (result == "running") {
localStorage.setItem("redirect", "yes");
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
}

function session0() {
var stats = localStorage.getItem("redirect");

if (stats == "yes") {
} else {
localStorage.setItem("session", "done");
}
localStorage.setItem("redirect", "no");
}
```

```html
<body onload="session1()" onunload="session0()">
<div style="background:skyblue">SESSION RUNNING</div>
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I open the page 3rd time it will not jump to google

Comment: Ill let the past version of the code here until i fix this multiple pages issue.

Comment: If it dont work, just clear your browser cache of today (since you have the error version stored). Anyway: [**live demo**](http://freestock.tk/single_instance_demo.html)

Comment: I'd like to ask you. If I have a series of webpages, for example, if user clicks a.html and will jump to b.html, what modification I need to make on your code so that when a user viewing either one of these 2 pages both of them are inaccessible for others??      @freestock.tk

Comment: I don't know if it is possible because of security reasons. Example: If a website knows that you have a local.storage(or cookie) on facebook named "myID" it would be a easy target to be acessed/edited by other external (malicious) websites. So i think the websites arent able to share local.storage and cookies; Maybe you can solve this with php, I'm not sure... If I find something, I'll let you know.

Comment: I have an idea: You can set a single page (example: session.html) and this page have an **iframe A**, then, user can click the button and open the **iframe B** and both will be under the same local.storage session (in this case, you let the javascript in the parent page, not inside the iframes).

Comment: I am using django to combine python and js, the user needs to submit a value and datasets in the first page and the second page will be shown with some downloadable files(these files will change every time), Is my situation still be suitable using your methods?   @freestock.tk

Comment: it can be a 100%heigth; 100% width iframe, so it isnt going to be noticed by the users.

Comment: So you mean only one html file but contain 2 iframe? First time the second frame is hidden? @freestock.tk

Comment: no, its a single iframe. But inside of it there is the page A.html and, when you click a link on A.html it goes (the iframe content, not the session.html) to the page B.html.

Comment: So actually there are 3 html? session.html, a.html and b.html??               @freestock.tk

Comment: Yes, and your javascript goes only on session.html

Comment: Can the localStorage used in a deployed website? I mean, if a user has entered this website, other users cannot log in to this website. Thank you @freestock.tk

Comment: You mean users from another computers? No. Because the local storage is **local** (the other users don't have access to your localstorage data). To do such a thing (allow only one logged user per time) you would need **php** or **asp.NET** (where your data goes to the **server**, not to a **local** storage;

Comment: **asp.NET** is more clean/advanced but only run in hosts with Windows (if you have a free host, your host probably run in Linux and do not support asp.NET). So the most common choice is **php**.

Comment: Thank you.I think I will use Apache later. And I think this can be set in maximum number of connection in Apache. Am I right? @freestock.tk

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know enought about Apache to tell you if it is possible or not; good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fiddle with localStorage and onbeforeunload event, something along the lines of:

```
    if(localStorage['visited'] == true){
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'This page is opened twice.';
    }

    localStorage['visited'] = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    localStorage['visited'] = false;
    }
```

Comment: I'd just add this to the bottom of my page within a <script> tag